# Radio Button as Tab pane controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

The Bootstrap tab pane has anchor tag as the tab controls, Instead of tab button look I need radio buttons.

Tried to add the radio buttons content of  tag

```
<div id="tab" class="btn-group" style="width=500px; margin-bottom:20px;">
  <a href="#accept" class="radio " data-toggle="tab" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; text-decoration: none;">
          <label>
             <input type="radio" value="accept" name="action" /> 
             Accept
          </label>
  </a>

  <a href="#discuss" class="radio" data-toggle="tab" style="float: right; text-decoration: none;">
          <label>
           <input type="radio" value="discuss" name ="action"/>
            Discuss
          </label>
  </a>
</div>
```

When a user clicks on the radio button a jquery script will trigger the tabs clicks, this works fine

```
$("input:radio").click(function(event) {
  $(event.target).parents('a').trigger('click');
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

the whole code  [Js fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/anand_jose_arackal/hkz8qogL/)

**Issue**

When a user click on the Label, tabs are selecting respectively but the radio button still in previous selections

The ways I tried to solve.
  1. Added CSS `pointer-events: none;` this will affect radio also.
  2. Script to check a radio button. this action call other js events

**What I need.**

A user only able to click the radio button, not tabs label part

**OR**

When User clicks on Tabs label, check the radio appropriate.

[Code Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/anand_jose_arackal/hkz8qogL/)

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to check the radio appropriate.

```js
$("input:radio").click(function() {
                $("#result").html($(this).val());
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tab" class="btn-group" style="width=500px; margin-bottom:20px;">
            <a href="#accept" class="radio " data-toggle="tab" style="float: left; margin-right: 20px; text-decoration: none;">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="accept" name="action" />
                    Accept
                </label>
            </a>

            <a href="#discuss" class="radio" data-toggle="tab" style="float: right; text-decoration: none;">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="discuss" name ="action"/>
                    Discuss
                </label>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="result"></div>
```

Hope this helps !